# Rabbitmq dying during startup, "epmd error for host"

Tags: rabbitmq

Rabbitmq keeps dying within 2 minutes of startup, and fails with the error:

```
ERROR: epmd error for host localhost: timeout (timed out)
```

The /etc/hosts file shows:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost []-MacBook-Pro []-MacBook-Pro.local
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

([] replaces actual name in file)

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Erlang (v20.3.8.3) and Rabbitmq via homebrew, and still no connection. This is also regardless of what wifi I am on, or if I'm disconnected from wifi. Other commands I have tried:

```
$ echo $HOSTNAME
localhost
$ hostname
localhost

$ ifconfig lo0
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=1203<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TXSTATUS,SW_TIMESTAMP>
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>

$ lsof -p 15279
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE   SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
epmd    15279 user  cwd    DIR                1,5        960       2 /
epmd    15279 user  txt    REG                1,5      46756 4852991 /usr/local/Cellar/erlang@20/20.3.8.3/lib/erlang/erts-9.3.3.2/bin/epmd
epmd    15279 user  txt    REG                1,5     841456 2333502 /usr/lib/dyld
epmd    15279 user  txt    REG                1,5 1170673664 3866438 /private/var/db/dyld/dyld_shared_cache_x86_64h
epmd    15279 user    0r   CHR                3,2        0t0     311 /dev/null
epmd    15279 user    1w   CHR                3,2        0t0     311 /dev/null
epmd    15279 user    2w   CHR                3,2        0t0     311 /dev/null
epmd    15279 user    3u  IPv4 0x91f821cb489372bb        0t0     TCP *:epmd (LISTEN)
epmd    15279 user    4u  IPv6 0x91f821cb3ac82ed3        0t0     TCP *:epmd (LISTEN)
epmd    15279 user    5u  IPv4 0x91f821cb4a2f057b        0t0     TCP localhost:epmd->localhost:55223 (ESTABLISHED)
epmd    15279 user    6u  IPv4 0x91f821cb3a64dc1b        0t0     TCP localhost:epmd->localhost:55470 (ESTABLISHED)
epmd    15279 user    7u  IPv4 0x91f821cb4919995b        0t0     TCP localhost:epmd->localhost:55974 (ESTABLISHED)
```

I'm not sure what else to try here, and am hoping someone has an idea.

Comment: What version of RabbitMQ? What is in the RabbitMQ logs? What is the output of the `hostname` command? Do you have a firewall enabled? Have you tried running the `generic-unix` RabbitMQ package rather than homebrew's?

Comment: rabbitmq: 3.7.7.  hostname is localhost (as seen above). I have both enabled and disabled a firewall, I enabled to make sure that port was available. As seen in another comment set, I can telnet to the port on localhost. I have not tried installing rabbitmq outside of home-brew, but because I'm trying to get this set up in a way that is replicatable for future env setups, I'd rather stick with brew?

Answer (score 1):

I think it likely means that the port `4369` is not accessible.

Also your hosts file is a little strange:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost []-MacBook-Pro []-MacBook-Pro.local
```

can you just make that:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

Comment: Originally the /etc/hosts file was 127.0.0.1 localhost only. I also tried separating the lines and adding them individually, but my boss (who has rabbitmq working) has the /etc/hosts file set up with 127.0.0.1 localhost [hostname1] [hostname2], so that's why it's where it is at now. You can also see on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13046/format-of-etc-hosts-on-linux-different-from-windows that this is a standard way of doing that.

Comment: Also, $ lsof -nP -i4TCP:4369 | grep LISTEN
epmd    15279 user    3u  IPv4 0x91f821cb489372bb      0t0  TCP *:4369 (LISTEN)
and localhost:log$ telnet localhost 4369
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.

Answer (score 0):

After getting help on the rabbitmq list, I discovered that rabbitmq was unable to log, and that's why it was quitting.

A bit more detail to help others in this, using epmd -d to start up epmd was useful to finally determine that rabbitmq was actually getting there, so that wasn't the issue in this case. But finding the erl_crash.dump file did show the error for not being able to log, so I changed the path in /usr/local/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf for the log file, and now it works.